# python or awk comparing files

Tags: python, awk

I have two files that are tab delimited.I need to compare file 1 column 3 to  file 2 column 1 .If there is a match I need to write column 2 of file 2 next to the matching line in file 1.here is a sample of my file:

file 1:

```
a rao rocky1 beta

b rao buzzy2 beta

c Rachel rocky2 alpha
```

file 2:

```
rocky1 highlightpath

rimper2 darkenpath

rocky2 greenpath
```

output:

new file:

```
a rao rocky1 beta highlightpath

b rao buzzy2 beta

c Rachel rocky2 alpha greenpath
```

the problem is file 1 is huge ! file 2 is also big but not as much.
So far I tried awk command , it worked partially. what I mean is number of lines in file 1 and output file which is newfile should be same, which is not what I got ! I get a difference of 20 lines.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$0;next}{if($1 in a){p=$1;$1="";print a[p],$0}}' file1 file2 > newfile
```

So I thought I could try python to do it, but I am a novice at python. All I know so far is I would like to make a dictionary for file 1 and file 2 and compare. I know how to read a file into dictionary and then I am blank.Any help and suggestion with the code will help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

# Usage: python SCRIPT.py FILE1 FILE2 > OUTPUT
file1, file2 = sys.argv[1:3]

# Store info from the smaller file in a dict.
d = {}    
with open(file2) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        k, v = line.split()
        d[k] = v

# Process the bigger file line-by-line, printing to standard output.
with open(file1) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.rstrip()
        k = line.split()[2]
        if k in d:
            print line, d[k]
        else:
            print line
```

Comment: @user2464553 I saw your comment. If you are getting an index error, it means some of the lines in FILE1 have fewer fields than you think: `split()` returns a list and `[2]` tries to get the list's 3rd element. Just add some conditional logic to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
          with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:

               for f1line in f1:
                    for f2line in f2:
                         ## remove new line character at end of each line
                         f1line = f1line.rstrip()
                         f2line = f2line.rstrip()

                         ## extract column fields
                         f1col3 = f1line.split('\t')[2]
                         f2col1 = f2line.split('\t')[0]

                         ## test if fields are equal
                         if (f1col3 == f2col1 ):
                              outfile.write('%s\t%s\n' % (f1line,
                                                          f2line.split('\t')[1]))
                         else:
                              outfile.write('%s\t\n' % (f1line))

                         break
```

- This script will compare lines1 of file1&2, then lines2 of file1&2, lines3 ... etc ...
- It is good for large files; shouldn't load the memory :)

Comment: There is a `break` in the F2 for-loop, so the F2 file iterator won't be exhausted after processing one line from F1... correct?

Comment: Yeah, didn't catch the `break` -- I guess because it's such an unexpected way to process two files in parallel. Maybe you could drop the inner loop altogether, and just use `f2line = next(f2, '')`, which seems to convey the algorithm more directly -- just a suggestion. Will delete my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

`file2` is set up to be the associative array and it's the smaller of the two files, so I re-arranged the awk a bit to get:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { if( length($1) > 0) a[$1]=$2; next} { if( $3 in a ) {print $0,a[$3] } else { print $0 } }' file2 file1 > newfile
```

1. For some reason, my machine wouldn't create `a[]` until I re-ordered the NR==FNR test, so that's a small difference.  Also note, I've made the first file handed to awk `file2`.  Non-empty lines from `file2` are added to `a[]`.
2. Process every line from `file1` secondly, and append the `file2` column 2 data to the line whenever `$3` in file1 is in `a[]`.  Else just print the line as is.

Running the above, I get the desired output on two different machines with different versions of awk ( from the generated `newfile` ):

```
a rao rocky1 beta highlightpath

b rao buzzy2 beta

c Rachel rocky2 alpha greenpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more short `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,$3 in a?a[$3]:""}' file2 file1
a rao rocky1 beta highlightpath

b rao buzzy2 beta

c Rachel rocky2 alpha greenpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing all the suggestions together:
I am getting none of these to work ! Maybe because of empty lines in my file 2? Well the lines are not completely empty. for example:

rocky1 highlightpath

rimper2 darkenpath

rocky2 greenpath

lacy2

lucy1  pembrooke

now when I ran the python codes given above I used a corrected file 2 where I took off the blanks lines (like lacy2) and then used the file. Eventhen I get list index out of range. Is the list that is being created with the lines from file is not right? looks like it. Please comment :)